# Zend PDF - get the width and height of an image?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, zend-pdf

I am creating my image like this:

```
$image1 = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($path);
```

Now, when I debug, I see _width and _height, but I cant access them using

```
$image1->_width;
```

because its protected. How do I get those values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
$image1->getPixelWidth();
$image1->getPixelHeight();
```